# More efficient way of using multiple SQL queries with WHERE clauses

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

Cant figure out how to set about this problem.

I am making a page that contains a large checklist. The aim is have the label and the check box value as dynamic values.

I have a DB table that is set up as so:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|     ID  |  name       |      value      |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|     1   |  checkbox1  |  checkbox1value |
|     2   |  checkbox2  |  checkbox2value |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```

What i am aiming to do is run a query on the database, and be able to set PHP variables for each of the rows.

So lets say the check list items look like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="<?php echo $val_checkbox1 ?>">

<label for="checkbox_id"><?php echo $label_checkbox1 ?></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id2" value="<?php echo $val_checkbox2 ?>">

<label for="checkbox_id2"><?php echo $label_checkbox2 ?></label>
```

I could run a basic:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = checkbox1"

$val_checkbox1 = $row['name'];

$label_checkbox1 = $row['value'];
```

But then i need to do that for every checkbox item and there will be 20+.

I need this so that the users can have an admin page and edit the values of the checkboxes them selves without ever needing access to the database.

I just need a way to set variables with their values from the database.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: You should change the name of your checkboxes either as `checkbox1`, `checkbox2`.. or `checkbox[]`

Comment: Sorry, its just an example of my checkboxes. Mine are named correctly, ready for the array but this was just quick to show how they are laid out.

Comment: don't use `WHERE name = checkbox1` and us a `while loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using PDO (which is more secure than the 
   older mysql libraries because it supports query parameters). */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Actual code example
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'.$row['id'].'" id="checkbox_'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['value'].'">';
    echo '<label for="checkbox_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</label>';
}
```

UPDATE:
A more general function:

```
// Actual code example
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    if($row['type']=='checkbox') {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'.$row['id'].'" id="checkbox_'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['value'].'">';
        echo '<label for="checkbox_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<label for="input_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</label>';
        echo '<input type="'.$row['type'].'" name="input'.$row['id'].'" id="input_'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['value'].'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think about a foreach but not in this way. I see this could work and shall give it a go!

Comment: actually, there are some select inputs in between the checkboxes. Ill have to go back to the drawing board with this :/

Comment: You could just add a 'type' field to the DB table and use (basically) the same code for those too/

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looks like this is the best way around it. Shall see if i can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Read them all and store them in an array.

```
$checkboxes = array();
$i = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $checkboxes[$i] = new array();
    $checkboxes[$i]['label'] = $row['label'];
    $checkboxes[$i]['value'] = $row['value'];
    $i++;
}
```

You could also use something else as the key for the array than the variable `$i` if you need another reference later on, maybe the label.